# Play framework/Jquery

Tags: jquery, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I am trying to use jquery to retrieve data from a JSON file. The file is recognized on the network, but it won't display any data. This is what I came up with, this piece of code is in index.scala.html Please let me know what I am doing wrong. The code outside the script works flawlessly. Also, newbie alert!

```
<script>

    console.log("hi");
  $.getJSON('assets/model_meta.json', function(data) {

        window.alert(data);
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in data.naraModelMeta) {
        output+="<li>" + data.naraModeMeta[i].label + " " + data.naraModeMeta[i].date + " " + data.naraModeMeta[i].c + " " + data.naraModeMeta[i].eps + " " + data.naraModeMeta[i].wp + " " + data.naraModeMeta[i].wn + " " + data.naraModeMeta[i].dictSize + " " + data.naraModeMeta[i].fromDate + " " + data.naraModeMeta[i].toDate + " " + data.naraModeMeta[i].vectorNum + "</li>";

        }


        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("meta_data").innerHTML=output;
        });

    </script>
```

this is what i have in controller:

```
  List data = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
  return ok(Json.toJson(data));
```

but the List and toJson show up as errors.

I also have a route set up. I am referencing this website if it helps: http://java.dzone.com/articles/jquery-ajax-play-2

Comment: You do not make it clear, are you running this script through a web browser, accessing the Scala page? The JSON file is on the server? Make sure you can access it directly via the browser.

Comment: @RobertMunn yes it's in the assets folder. I am running the application in localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two import 1) import java.util.Arrays; // for array
2)import play.libs.Json; //for json

then try running url in browser , you will be able to see json response.

Comment: your are parsing wrong json output. please correct that . After reading your controller code you will be having json response similar to ['foo','bar']. And you are parsing some thing else.

Comment: i am really confused what you are saying. it prints out fine in the controller but not when i try to pass it to the template.